# If statements not treated as boolean?

Tags: if-statement, vb6, language-agnostic, pseudocode

I'm a student, and my software teacher gave us this example -

```
BEGIN
IF first < second
    THEN display first,second
ELSE
    display second,first
ENDIF
END
```

If the two numbers, first and second were the same (say 2,2), the ELSE path would be taken, as first < second evaluates to false and so doesn't execute.

However, my software teacher said that in certain languages, both numbers being the same would be problematic and cause errors or strange behaviour (I believe he cited Visual Basic as an example). I do not see how this is possible. An IF statement is evaluated as either true or false and so one of the options MUST run and there should be no problem in evaluating whether 2 is less than 2.

Although he is my teacher and I respect him as such, I do not trust him completely and he does make errors at times. Is what he's said correct? And if so, could I have some specific examples of what happens?
Thanks.

Comment: show him an example in VB, or some other language that's easy to access like javascript

Comment: I've can't recall hearing of a language where an ELSE wasn't guaranteed if an IF was false. Even Visual Basic. I think asking him for an example would be good. :)

Comment: Any chance he mentioned short-circuit evaluation? Visual Basic does not do it by default, and it can be quite unexpected coming from C-style languages.

Comment: Aah, possibly. Could you give me a bit of a run down on this? @AntonGogolev

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/486722/60188

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps he is talking (in a round about way) about floating point imprecision?

> there should be no problem in evaluating whether 2 is less than 2.

This is not always the case for some numbers stored using an imprecise representation, for example:

```
Dim first As Double, second As Double

 first = 0.3
second = 0.1 + 0.2

If first < second Then
    Debug.Print first, "is less than", second
Else
    Debug.Print "equal or greater"
End If
```

Outputs:

> `0.3 is less than 0.3`

See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

This can manifest more visibly when one exceeds the safe bounds of a floating point type, for example in JavaScript:

```
> 9007199254740992 == 9007199254740993
< true
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the `expression` in `if (expression)` always evaluates to a boolean. At least that is true in C, C++, PHP, Java, .NET, Python, Javascript...

But maybe it is not the case in some old or less-used languages.

For Visual Basic, [this Microsoft documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/215yacb6.aspx) clearly says that `number < number` will evaluate to `FALSE`.

Comment: Okay, I didn't think this was a common thing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well  clearly a < a is false, if a is Integer(not fractional number). However in case of **fractional number this may  be true of false.** Let me give you instance of each for c language. C compiler uses IEEE-754 number  representation for floating point.

take a=0.1273(stored in memory as:0.1272999423027039)

take b=0.12 and c=0.0073+b

now if you  check,  **c 
   It is true**.